# MySQL trigger: if record exists just update

Tags: mysql, trigger, insert

There is a MySQL database with the following table reviews(***reviewer***, ***product***, score, title, comment, creation_date, last_modified).
It is needed a trigger before insertion to check if the user has already reviewed the same product. If so, just update the fields score, title, comment and last_modified. This mean no insertion.
Otherwise no operation is needed from the trigger and the review is inserted as usually.

N.B. **primary key is bold**, *foreign key is italic*

I tried something myself but I am confident enough to say it does not work:

```
DELIMITER /
CREATE TRIGGER update_review BEFORE INSERT ON reviews
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF ((SELECT reviews.reviewer, reviews.product FROM reviews WHERE reviews.reviewer=new.reviewer AND reviews.product=new.product)) THEN
SET old.score=new.score AND old.title=new.title AND old.comment=new.comment AND old.last_modified=new.last_modified;
END IF;
END /
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> check if the user has already reviewed the same product. If so, just update the fields score, title, comment and last_modified.

No trigger! Use `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

```
INSERT INTO reviews (reviewer, 
                     product, 
                     score, 
                     title, 
                     comment, 
                     creation_date, 
                     last_modified)
VALUES (@reviewer, 
        @product, 
        @score, 
        @title, 
        @comment, 
        @creation_date, 
        @last_modified)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE score = VALUES(score),
                        title = VALUES(title),
                        comment = VALUES(comment)
                        last_modified = VALUES(last_modified);
```

Additionally - define `creation_date` field as `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `last_modified` field as `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, then remove them from all INSERT/UPDATE queries - they will be updated automatically.